# Does IE7 have a "developer mode" or plugin like Firefox/Chrome/Safari?

Tags: html, css, browser, internet-explorer-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Debugging JavaScript in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361635/debugging-javascript-in-ie7)

Firefox has Web Developer plugin and Firebug for troubleshooting html/css/javascript issues. Google Chrome and Safari have a very similar console and right-click options for "Inspect Element".

Does IE7 have anything similar for troubleshooting layout/html/css issues?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yes - The Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar

[Download details: Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=95E06CBE-4940-4218-B75D-B8856FCED535&displaylang=en)

Comment: Tt works poorly in comparison to Firebug, debugbar is better.

Comment: In particular, you can't debug Javascript

Comment: The link in the answer doesn't point to toolbar that is compatible with IE7 anymore. Instead, I found that debugbar works well, as pointed out in another answer below.

Answer (score 14):

You can also use [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html), wich works on IE, Opera and Safari.

It's a Javascript implementation that you can load with a simple bookmarklet.

As SO doesn't allow Javascript, here is the bookmarklet source code (just copy paste to your browser location bar (always make sure it's safe before executing random javascript (In any case check the first link)))

```
javascript:var%20firebug=document.createElement('script');firebug.setAttribute('src','http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/1.2/firebug-lite-compressed.js');document.body.appendChild(firebug);(function(){if(window.firebug.version){firebug.init();}else{setTimeout(arguments.callee);}})();void(firebug);
```

Firebug Lite supports [all basic commands](http://getfirebug.com/console.html) of Firebug.

Comment: This is mind blowing! Firebug in IE7 and Safari is a dream come true!

Answer (score 7):

I have also used [Debug Bar](http://www.debugbar.com/).

Comment: I've just downloaded it, and Debug Bar doesn't seem to do JS debugging.

Answer (score 5):

Check out the [IE Developer toolboar](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359).

Answer (score 2):

[Web Development Helper](http://projects.nikhilk.net/WebDevHelper/)

*Web Development Helper is a free browser extension for Internet Explorer that provides a set of tools and utilities for the Web developer, esp. Ajax and ASP.NET developers. The tool provides features such as a DOM inspector, an HTTP tracing tool, and script diagnostics and immediate window.
Web Development Helper works against IE6+, and requires the .NET Framework 2.0 or greater to be installed on the machine.
Once installed, the tool can be activated using the Tools | Web Development Helper command. You can also customize your browser's toolbar to add a button for this command to facilitate frequest use. Clicking on the menu command or browser button brings up the tool's console window and set of commands.
Page Features:
DOM inspector allows viewing all elements, selected elements, or elements matching an ID or CSS class, their attributes and styles. 
Capturing a screen shot of the current page. 
Viewing page information such as metadata, tags, and linked resources.* .......

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately it seems microsoft have discontinued it, the page for the toolbar now just says 'We are sorry, the page you requested cannot be found.'

I reckon because its built into 8 they have removed it for download, and cant be bothered with helping out us devs who are forced to make our projects work in their more archaic browsers :'(

Also before anyone says it, IE8 compatability mode != IE7

Answer (score 1):

There's a [toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en) you can get but it still doesn't match up to Firefox, especially for javascript debugging.

IE8 will be a huge improvement for development.

Answer (score 1):

The following is specifically for IE7, other versions are probably similar.

Here is the new link to the developmment tools from microsoft.(as of 4-26-2011)  [IE Development Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=95e06cbe-4940-4218-b75d-b8856fced535)

Once installed, you will need to enable the toolbar.

To Enable, click on `Tools | Manage Add-Ons | Enable or Disable Add-ons`, to enable the addon.

To add the icon to the IE Toolbar, right click on the `IE menu | Customize Command Bar | Add or Remove Commands`.  Add the "< (arrow) >" icon.

Hope that helps.

Comment: isnt this a repost to the accepted question?

Comment: @toxicate20 yeah, but I don't mind it because he explains how to enable the toolbar/icon

Answer (score 0):

You can also use IE watch, which is like firebug, but you need to buy it. It is a 30 days trail version.

Answer (score -8):

Actually, the best add-on for developers to IE would be [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/version.asp). It has a number of features that the other browsers possess.

Comment: Fiddler looks like it has some interesting features for debugging HTTP issues, but I don't see anything for troubleshooting HTML/CSS layout issues - which is what I was really asking for.

Comment: -1, Fiddler is not related to the question