# What tools should I have as my core set for developing javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have been developing **ASP.Net** applications for quite a few years, and I have always avoided learning **JavaScript**. Now I have been diving in and trying to learn as much as possible.

As a **.Net** developer I rely on **Visual Studio** heavily. What I am wondering is what tools, as a **JavaScript** developer, do you guys rely on heavily to develop **JavaScript**? I have just discovered **FireBug** which is awesome. What other tools out there am I missing that are a **must have**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Firebug is awesome.  Be sure that you are aware of the [profiling](http://getfirebug.com/js.html) capabilities in there.  Also, there is a new testing framework called [FireUnit](http://fireunit.org/) that works with Firebug as well.

I like [Textmate](http://macromates.com/) for Javascript editing on my Mac.  [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/) (stand-alone or as an [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org) plug-in) is really good too.

I've been meaning to try test-driven-development in Javascript with the [YUI test library](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/yuitest/).  It promises to be like NUnit/JUnit for Javascript, which would be great.

Check out [JS lint](http://www.jslint.com/).

If you're interested in Aspect-oriented Programming, look at AOP in Javascript from [Dojo](http://lazutkin.com/blog/2008/may/18/aop-aspect-javascript-dojo/).

Lastly, for some good information about the current state of Javascript engines (cool stuff like [TraceMonkey](https://wiki.mozilla.org/JavaScript:TraceMonkey)) and future directions, check out this episode of [HanselMinutes](http://www.hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=148).

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

Firebug is pretty much the best. You'll need some solutions for IE too.

See this link: [Debugging JavaScript in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361635/debugging-javascript-in-ie7)

Answer (score 2):

1. Visual Studio 2008 - has JavaScript
   intellisense and integrated Js
   debugging capability
2. FireBug - a
   must have for any web developer
3. [FireBug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html) - "The solution is
       Firebug Lite, a JavaScript file you
       can insert into your pages to
       simulate some Firebug features in
       browsers that are not named
       "Firefox"."
4. [JsLint](http://www.jslint.com) - gotta make
   sure what you're writing is of
   decent quality, and JsLint will help
   you do that

Answer (score 2):

Other useful tools:

- [packer](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/) really good JavaScript compressor.
- [Web Developer extension for Firefox](http://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/60)
- JsUnit unit testing framework.
- [SeleniumIDE](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/)  feature, user interface and acceptance testing.

Answer (score 1):

Lately, Visual Studio itself has improved considerably in its JavaScript support. For example, IntelliSense is now available for JavaScript in VS2008, including for third-party libraries such as [jQuery](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/21/jquery-intellisense-in-vs-2008.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Why not continue to use the Visual Studio for convenience and download jQuery with intellisense support.

Scott Guthrie has a post on how to do it

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/21/jquery-intellisense-in-vs-2008.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/09/28/jquery-and-microsoft.aspx