# Debugging CSS issues in IE7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, debugging, internet-explorer-7

I need to debug some annoying CSS issues on IE7, I have the Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar installed. It is having trouble resolving all of the styles that are being applied.

I am also using [Firebug lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html), it is helpful but way too basic.

Debugging this stuff in Firefox is not an option due to the poor design of this intranet web site.

Are there any other tools I can use that will help me debug CSS issues on IE7.

Related question: [Debugging JavaScript in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361635/debugging-javascript-in-ie7).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found [DebugBar](http://www.my-debugbar.com) and it seems to be giving me quite a lot of help.

Comment: yup debugbar is somewhat great but lacks the ability to modify the CSS directly.

Answer (score 0):

XRAY is a bookmarklet that is very helpfull for cross browser debugging.

[Link](http://www.westciv.com/xray/)

Comment: Im unable to get it to work with my intranet site (it works fine with external sites), it does not help me trace which file and which line contains the dodgy css ...

Comment: it does not show up on local sites for some reason, and its output is a little basic

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome's 'inspect element' was very helpful for me - especially for markup I hadn't written myself. Being able to see which element referenced which stylesheet was a godsend.