# Programmatically access webpage error details in browsers

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, browser, google-chrome

Is there some way to access webpage warning/error details using JavaScript?

For instance, errors in IE show up in the bottom left corner like so:
[image]

I would like to able to access the details of this error (in IE as well as other browsers if possible) using JavaScript.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: I'm not looking for debuggers. I want to access the content of the error details/error console. Alternately, figuring out how to create a global exception handler equivalent for JavaScript would help too

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361635/debugging-javascript-in-ie7

Comment: thanks, but that's not what I'm looking for. I want to specifically access the contents of the error details in IE or error console in other browsers.

Alternately, figuring out how to create a global exception handler equivalent for JavaScript would help too...

I'll update my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to use the `window.onerror` event. You can consider this event as a sort of global exception handler. The value returned by `onerror` determines whether the browser displays a standard error message. If you return false, the browser displays the standard error message in the JavaScript console. If you return true, the browser does not display the standard error message. ([Source](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/error.shtml))

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onerror=function(msg, url, line){
        alert('An error has occurred' + msg);
        return true;
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Syntax error
    document.write('hi there'
</script>
```

You can also use traditional exception handling in JavaScript to catch run-time errors.

```
try
{
    document.write(junkVariable)
}
catch (exception)
{
    document.write(exception)
}
```

The output of the above would be:

```
‘junkVariable’ is undefined
```

**EDIT:** As noted by [psychotik's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106095/psychotik) comment, the `window.onerror` event does not work in Google Chrome. ([Source](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=7771))

Comment: is there any way to do this at a global level, like how you have global SEH for Windows apps? Is the `onerror` event something of the sort?

Comment: Or even better, you could just `document.write()` the `exception` object as it's `toString()` method will return `TypeError: 'junkVariable' is undefined`, giving more info as to what type of error was thrown.

Comment: @Elijah Grey: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. Will edit my answer.

Comment: Great -- thanks! FWIW, onerror has the following arguments: msg, url, linenumber

Comment: @psychotik: Yes, you can get the error message from the `msg` param.

Comment: FYI -- this doesn't work in Chrome. http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=7771

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/error.html <-- this doesn't work a lot of places, but `try { } catch( ){ }` around your code does, :)