# Why is it that on IE7, my javascript file does not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

No functions get called, and I can't even alert.
It is just an external javascript file.

However, everything works on Firefox, Chrome and IE8.

I am using Django/python backened to serve this file.
Is this a known bug from IE7?

Comment: Does IE shows any errors? Can you provide the source code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the generic nature of the question the best answer would be found in the answer to another question:

**Debugging JavaScript in IE7:**
[Debugging JavaScript in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361635/debugging-javascript-in-ie7/361671#361671)

Using these debug tools you can find out exactly what is going wrong with IE7 in particular.

Comment: THanks. In the end, we used  JSLINT to determine that we had an extra comma at the end of a dictionary