# Debugger for IE7

Tags: php, internet-explorer-7, firebug

I m using PHP5 & during testing on IE7 if some thing does no work then i can not find the bug quickly as i can do in FF (by the help of Firebug).

Is there any tool for code debugging in **IE7** like in **FireFox** we have **firebug** ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361635/debugging-javascript-in-ie7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See these [question & answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361635/debugging-javascript-in-ie7) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

there is [Firebug Light](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite)

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar plugin for IE as well. Try [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite/ie.html)