# Sharepoint Page Error: Object Expected

Tags: sharepoint

I am using Custom Masterpage in my sharepoint site and i did lot of customization through SPD allmost all the pages.

**I am getting a crazy error down on the status Error: Object expected in only in IE browser and not in Mozilla.**

Note: I am using some javascript/JQuery in the Masterpage and Dropped a Webpart in Masterpage without WebpartZone which i needed in common for all the pages.  Will that be a problem??

Please help me on this

Comment: Have you actually tried debugging the Javascript...?

Comment: @Brandon Moretz, No i didn't...how to actually debug the javascript?

Comment: There are a *million* possible reasons for this. Debug the javascript to see a stack trace and see if you can get a better idea there. Note that IE's javascript debugger is terrible. Often times the most practical course of action is to revert to a known working state (or in this case using the default/v4 master page), and narrowing down which change causes the error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361635/debugging-javascript-in-ie7

Comment: @Brandon Moretz what option in IE Developer makes debug the javascript in the page