# IE7 drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on a site and got stuck. The problem is that my drop down menu doesn't appear on my home page while on other pages it's working fine. I got this situation in IE7. Other browsers are working fine. Here is my link, kindly help:

http://www.sifrek.com/demo/remserv/index.htm

Comment: Also, why don't you try posting some code and other helpful information, like what you've tried so far, what plug-in you're using for the drop down menus, and any other information that might be helpful in helping you. My advice is enable the IE7 debugger and look and see if the browser is throwing any errors.

Comment: You're welcome :)  Good luck!  [Enable Script Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z959x58c.aspx) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361635/debugging-javascript-in-ie7

Comment: i'm using moodropmenu.js

Comment: Your example link is now dead, which is not helpful for answering you question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a Javascript or a jQuery problem. Just a CSS problem on IE7. Add this to your CSS and try again.

```css
#nav li { z-index: 2; }
```