# IE7 page hang, suspect due to javascript but how can I diagnose this?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

I've looked at Web Dev Helper as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361635/debugging-javascript-in-ie7) SO post, but doesn't look like it's going to help.

I don't seem to have a means of getting info out with regard to what the page is doing when the hang starts? Any known technique for this sort of issue?

Comment: It should say "error on page" or something at the bottom of the browser. You should be able to debug from there although I've never found the messages very useful. Have you got a link? Might help.

Comment: Do you have to posibility to debug with a different browser (like Firefox with Firebug)?

Comment: The page is freezing before I even see a script error. No link as this is on a dev server at the moment.

Comment: @Matthias - this behaviour is IE7 specific. No other browsers affected so little point in debugging in other browsers I suspect

Comment: @Cognize - have you tried ripping your JS out and adding it back in a bit at a time to try and localise the issue?

Comment: I usually add a lot of alerts to see how far the script gets before failing.

Comment: @pikand - I do this as well. Specially in older browsers where the dev tools are non existent or terrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for my info and anyone whose interested, this was due to an action that runs on window resize. This event seemed to fire almost constantly for IE7. A timeout script enabled me to get some control back here.

```
var resizeTimeout;
    var actioning = false;

    $(window).resize(function() {

        if(!actioning ) {

            actioning = true;

            resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {

                clearTimeout(resizeTimeout);

                .. do stuff

            }, 200);
        }
    });
```