# Why won't Visual Web Developer act as my Javascript debugger for IE7?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging, internet-explorer-7, visual-studio-debugging

I need to debug some JS that isn't working in IE7, so I installed Visual Web Developer 2010 Express into my IE7 virtual machine, with the intention of [using it to debug whatever I want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/778498/907826). But when I get a Javascript error in IE7, I only get the generic "problems with this website" message, and no debugger:

[image: IE7 generic Javascript error popup]

"Disable script debugging" is **off** in Internet Options and "Display a notification about every script error" is **on**. I have tried resetting the default settings for both IE and Visual Web Developer, and disabling all add-ons for IE.

Anybody know what gives?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your default browser is set to the browser you're trying to test against (in this case, IE 7). When you start debugging your empty project in Visual Wed Developer, it should open the default browser.

Not sure about the nature of it, but some magic happens behind the scenes that enables the script engine in IE to be exposed to the developer through the IDE.