# IE issue - Object.keys(value).length not supported

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I've been trying to debug some js in Internet Explorer, and I can't figure this one out. Here's the line that is causing the error:

```
var numberOfColumns = Object.keys(value).length;
```

And the error is...

```
Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 640
Char: 5
Code: 0
URI: xxx
```

At first I thought it had something to do with the `Object.keys(value).length;` property, but strangely (for me anyways), the error is at char 5, which is the beginning of the variable name.

Anyways, I have no idea what's going on or how to fix it. Also, if I replace:

```
var numberOfColumns = Object.keys(value).length;
```

With ...

```
var numberOfColumns = 9; // troubleshooting
```

The error persists. Please help.

**Update**

jsFiddle added

http://jsfiddle.net/4Rab7/

Comment: did you try to run it with firebug, or any other debug tool?

Comment: can you show some more code, maybe a jsfiddle with the issue

Comment: If you replace the supposedly faulty code with non-faulty code and it still fails, odds are the problem is something else.

Comment: My company blocks certain sites, and it just so happens the FF addons page, as well as a tool I found in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361635/debugging-javascript-in-ie7, are blocked. But yeah, I'll have a jsfiddle ready in just a second

Comment: I updated the question with a simple jsFiddle implementation. In IE 8, there is no alert, but in Firefox, it works.

Comment: Use the developer tools (F12) to determine whether a feature is supported in your browser or not. For instance, typing `Object.keys` into the console of both IE10 and Chrome reveal `function keys() { [native code] }`, showing they support this method.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `keys` property is supported in IE >= 9. You are probably testing it in an earlier version. A simple workaround is:

```
var length = 0;
for(var prop in data){
    if(data.hasOwnProperty(prop))
        length++;
}
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/vKr8a/

See this compatibility table for more info:

http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/

Comment: Awesome, I just figured out the solution but yours is much simpler (and better) than mine: http://jsfiddle.net/xDfBZ/ . I'll definitely go with yours

Comment: this pollutes `prop` global var

Comment: @StevenLu You could use `for (var prop in data)`.

Comment: Yes that is what this answer should be if you want to avoid my downvote :P

Comment: Are we sure keys is actually supported in IE >= 9? I am running IE11, and it still doesn't supports it lol, did they decided to remove it?

Comment: @codenamezero Yes, I'm sure it is supported in IE>=9. Make sure your page isn't in quirks mode.

Comment: Yes I hit this issue in IE11 also, in compatibility mode.

Comment: This is the best solution: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys   scroll down to the polyfill

Answer (score 13):

Alternatively, you could use a recommended polyfill for browsers that don't natively support `Object.keys`

```
Object.keys=Object.keys||function(o,k,r){r=[];for(k in o)r.hasOwnProperty.call(o,k)&&r.push(k);return r}
```

A break down of what this script does:

```
Object.keys = Object.keys || function(o,k,r) { 
// If the script doesn't detect native Object.keys 
// support, it will put a function in its place (polyfill)

    r=[];
    // Initiate the return value, empty array

    for(k in o) r.hasOwnProperty.call(o,k) 
    // loop through all items in the object and verify each
    // key is a property of the object (`for in` will return non 
    // properties)

    && r.push(k);
    // if it is a property, save to return array

    return r
}
```

Comment: Clean, simple, & effective.

Answer (score 4):

`Object.keys` has been introduced in ECMAScript 5th Edition. So if you IE-version is lower than 9, it will not be supported.