# Javascript trying to iterate through an array of objects to display their properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, foreach

I have a json object that contains an array of objects with similar properties.  I'm trying to iterate through the array for each of the objects and display their individual properties.  Here's what I have so far...

```
Object.keys(jsoncont)
    .sort(function(a,b) {
        return b.localeCompare(a)
})
.forEach(function(key) {
    var val = jsoncont[key];

    $('#contactSearchResults').html('<div class="resultset"><input type="radio" name="customer_c_id" value="' + val.id + '" /></div><div class="resultset">' + val.first + '</div><div class="resultset">' + val.last + '</div><div class="resultset">' + val.email + '</div>');

});
```

This is only returning one object in the array.  Can someone explain to me how to iterate through all the objects instead of just returning the first result in the key?

Comment: Does the script start after the onload event?

Comment: Just as a side note, be mindful when using `Object.keys` as it's only supported in ***IE >= 9***. For more information, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13723805/ie-issue-object-keysvalue-length-not-supported) question.

Comment: Please don't support IE8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because you're setting the content of `#contactSearchResults` each iteration. Try changing it to `append` if you want to print them all out to the DOM

```
$('#contactSearchResults').append('<div class="resultset"><input type="radio" name="customer_c_id" value="' + val.id + '" /></div><div class="resultset">' + val.first + '</div><div class="resultset">' + val.last + '</div><div class="resultset">' + val.email + '</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var allitems = "";
Object.keys(jsoncont)
.sort(function(a,b) {
    return b.localeCompare(a)
})
.forEach(function(key) {
    var val = jsoncont[key];

    allitems += '<div class="resultset"><input type="radio" name="customer_c_id" value="' + val.id + '" /></div><div class="resultset">' + val.first + '</div><div class="resultset">' + val.last + '</div><div class="resultset">' + val.email + '</div>';
});
$('#contactSearchResults').html(allitems)
```