# Page has two scripts. One runs on all browsers. One fails on IE7.

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm no js expert but I've minimised my faulty script and tried to localise the fault without success. You can find the actual page at www.trinitywoking.org.uk. but my minimal test case is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">
<title>MinTestCase</title>
<script>window.onload = function () { // Don't run script until page is loaded
var votd = new Array();  
votd[129]="Mount Sinai was all smoke because God had come down on it as fire.";
// Prepare today's string for display
document.getElementById("keyverse").innerHTML="<p> "  +  votd[(129)] + "</p> ";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Target paragraph follows </h1>
<p id="keyverse">
</p>  
</body>
</html>
```

This runs and displays correctly on all browsers except IE lte 8.
A second script runs on all browsers so it doesn't look like a permissions issue.

I'll be very grateful for any help with this.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is Microsofts blasphemy filter kicking in ?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the issue to see if there is an error? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361635/debugging-javascript-in-ie7

Comment: You're trying to put a `<p>` inside a `<p>`, which is not valid.

Comment: i can only see one JavaScript function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `<p>` tags in `document.getElementById()` line:

```
document.getElementById("keyverse").innerHTML=votd[(129)];
```

There are already tags where you try to edit the `innerHTML`. IE is a **very** picky browser.

Comment: Thank you so much, @imulsion. Of course it is so obvious, I should have kicked myself. The min test case runs perfectly when I fix that. I've repeated a very similar error on the same line of but I should be able to sort that easily.

Comment: @user2366463 no problem, that's what I'm here for :) We all have these "kick ourselves" problems; I've had a few myself ;)