# jQuery ajax page not loading in ie7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I am loading a piece of content via jQuery .load - All works as expected except for ie7 which doesn't load anything.

The ajax page (camera.php) does contain its own jQuery which seems to be the problem. If I take the script out, it does load.

```
$("#CameraBegin").click(function () {
    var ajax_load = "<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' />";
    $("#ContentLoad").html(ajax_load).load("camera.php", function (data) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#CameraQ1").offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

I have tried adding - $.getScript("js/camera.js"); (to get the jquery I need separately) which also works in everything except ie7.

Just wondering if there is a work around to reliably load the jQuery I need in ie7

the .on method isn't an option

Comment: What jQuery version are you using? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: jQuery v@1.8.1 - no errors showing

Comment: Why on earth does one still develop for IE7?!?

Comment: its a client request unfortunately for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with your AJAX call. There is an error in your `camera.js` that only happens in IE7. It can be numerous things, really (for example IE7 does not like when you put a comma after the last element of an array - most browsers are lenient with this).

You should debug your code in IE7 and fix stuff it does not like:

- [Debugging JavaScript in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361635/debugging-javascript-in-ie7)

Comment: Annoyingly yes. Minor bugs in both the html and the js in the ajax page. Spent a day trying - only to find an unclosed div and missing semi colon we breaking it. Make sure your code is perfect in ajax page loads as older versions of ie don't forgive.

Comment: @Jeff You should make sure your code is perfect anyways, otherwise be prepared for unexpected results :).

Comment: very true - im still blaming ie though