# Is there any JavaScript debugger for IE < 8?

Tags: internet-explorer, javascript-debugger

Is there any light-weight JavaScript debugger for IE < 8?

I've been using Visual Studio, but it's a bit of a hassle when you need to install it to a client computer to debug IE7 and lower...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debugging JavaScript in IE7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361635/debugging-javascript-in-ie7)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Firebug Lite](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite).

Simply include the following code in your master page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js"></script>
```