# How do a I debug IE7 script errors with no line or character number?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, modern.ie

**Before you ask**: the only reason I'm using IE7 in 2015 is to test that 'upgrade your browser' messages appear for IE7/IE8/IE9.

[image]

IE7 says I have a script error. It has:

- A line number of 0
- A character of 0
- No other messages

How can I start to debug this? Is there something I can do to get a real line number / character number or a real error message?

Comment: If you open up developer tools in IE7 it usually displays a more accurate javascript error in the console.

Comment: @wildavies IE7 has a Developer Toolbar, but that toolbar has no console.

Comment: Related: [Debugging JavaScript in IE7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361635/debugging-javascript-in-ie7)

Comment: Ah I forgot about that. You could attempt to open it in IE9 and change to IE7 mode. Often you get the same js error and IE9 does have a console.

Comment: usually the line/char info is missing because the error resulted from activity within an eval() statement.