# Is there any develop tool for IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, browser

my website looks good in Chrome and Firefox but in IE, everything is in messy.
I just want to figure out which css is not good.

So is there any develop tool in IE likes Firebug in Firefox or develop tool in Chrome.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56615/does-ie7-have-a-developer-mode-or-plugin-like-firefox-chrome-safari?rq=1
or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361635/debugging-javascript-in-ie7 or a billion of the same questions on stack. Its better to search stack before posting a question.

Comment: Try googling "Is there any develop tool for IE" before you ask StackOverflow.

Comment: what version of IE do you use?

Comment: You can also use firebug lite https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE8 and up includes a "Developer Tools" feature, which can be accessed via F12, just like Firebug.

It isn't anything like as good as Firebug or the Chrome Dev tools, but it does exist, and is useful for debugging your code.

By the way, one of the main reasons for sites that look good in other sites to break badly in IE is if you haven't specified a valid DOCTYPE. This will throw the site into "Quirks mode". This can be resolved by adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` as the first line of the HTML code. IE's dev tools window will show you if the page is in quirks mode -- this is probably the first thing you should check.

Answer (score 2):

Latest IE version includes a developer tool. If im not mistaken you can open it by pressing F12.

Comment: The "F12" tools have been *part of* IE since IE 8.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359

The Microsoft Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar provides a variety of tools for quickly creating, understanding, and troubleshooting Web pages.

Comment: This is for IE6/7. IE8+ have their own integrated tools. (Press F12).

Comment: Thanks for giving me more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try Internet Explorer development tools  (since 8 version)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Google Web Toolkit is another alternative

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideIE9