# CSS and Button issue occurs only in IE7 and Windows Server 2008

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-7, css3pie

I have a CSS issue that appears to only be reproducable when viewing the webpage in IE7 on a Windows 2008 web server. The issue does not occur when viewing the page on my dev version of the website (which is a widnows 7 environment). Note: the windows 2008 server and dev code (and database data) are the same.

The problem is when a popup is displayed, one of the buttons poistion is not updated (actually, the image for the button is not updated, the button itself has moved but is not displayed as such). This kind of problem is usually straight forward to fix because you can inspect the elements in IE9, but in this case you can't see the HTML that is output and you cannot select the elements in the popup. I cannot reproduce this on my dev machnine and cannot inspect the button element in the browser as you usually would be able to.

Are there any known issues that can be caused simply by websites being hosted on certain versions of windows server? (I can't think of anything else that's different beteween dev environment and the server)

I have researched on the internet but there seems to be very little regarding this specific issue. The best guess I have is that it may be caused by something being used by the site called PIE.htc and it may be one of the issues listed here: [http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/][1]

[1]: http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/ but this is a long shot and I have no way of verifying whether this is the case because the code must first be deployed to the 2008 server (I cannot reproduce it in dev environment and cannot inspect elements)

I cannot think what else could be causing this issue so any any suggestions will be very much appreciated.

Comment: You could use the standalone Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar for IE7 - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56615/does-ie7-have-a-developer-mode-or-plugin-like-firefox-chrome-safari

Comment: It would be cool if you could remove PIE.htc to check whether it's causing you problem, which is VERY possible... Does resizing the window, hovering elements or scrolling ever change the position of you button?

Comment: @Dash - I can inspect the other elements in the page (in IE9's IE7 mode), just not the popup that has the button in the wrong position.

Comment: @Armel L - yes that's a good idea. It does sound as though that's the only likley thing that could be causing it so far. Perhaps even changing <fieldset> tag to <div> tag? Have you come accross issues such as this related to PIE.htc?

Comment: @Armel L - and yes, moving the dev bar up and down again over the button causes it to move to it's correct position - why is this?

Comment: @aspdotnetuser Yes, every time I work with css3pie... Some events (resize, mouseover...) need to trigger so pie's script positions its generated elements, and sometimes it needs to be forced.

Comment: @Armel L - in that case, how can I fix it?

Comment: @aspdotnetuser Via javascript, you can change css properties on the faulty element (like display: none and then display: block) so it gets repainted.

Comment: @Armel L - so when the page/elements have loaded, set a property like 'display:none or display:block' on the button and it should redraw it again in the correct position?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16873/discussion-between-armel-l-and-aspdotnetuser)

Comment: @Armel L, I can't at the moment. I will try your suggestion of adding javascript and will post back later.